# Unexpected Error in Selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

I am getting a Unexpected error in some of the Selenium RC code. Some time it works fine but sometimes it gives the Unexpected error and the scripts stop at that line only.

Example:

There is script for "Login" than it click on the link than fills some form than press some button.

Sometimes its run till Login, sometimes till click of a link sometimes it executes full.

Please give me some solution for this its urgent.

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide an answer. A sample of your HTML source and test code would help, as well as details of any investigation you've already performed.

Comment: am writing it in Seleninium - RC  and language I am using is Java. The snippet is as follows

selenium.type("__ac_name", userName);
   selenium.type("__ac_password", passWord);
   selenium.click("submit");
   selenium.waitForPageToLoad(_PAGELOADTIME);
   
   selenium.click("link=Supplemental Resources");
   selenium.waitForPageToLoad(_PAGELOADTIME);

there more code but i write in this way only some time it works and somtimes not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setspeed(timeout).
After you declare your selenium Hash variable, for it to take at least "timeout" miliseconds between each selenium test case